# 從上次我們去那個咖啡店這次是第一次去了: This is the first time at the coffee shop since the last time we went?

Tags: translation, mandarin, cantonese

Trying to translate `This is the first time at the coffee shop since the last time we went` produced these two sentences, which feel incorrect for Chinese grammar.

```
從上次我們去那個咖啡店這次是第一次去了

從上次我們去那個咖啡店，我從來沒去過。這次是第一次去le。
```

1) In Mandarin, what would be the right translation for `This is the first time at the coffee shop since the last time we went`?

2) What would the Cantonese translation be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the first time at the coffee shop since the last time we went

In Mandarin, I will put : 自从上次去过这家咖啡店后，我这还是头一次来.

Comment: would it be correct to use this as the second half? 我還是第一次來。 全句子：自從上次去了那家咖啡店後，我這次還是第一次來。

Comment: @Crashalot yeah, that sounds fine

Comment: also 去了 is better than 去過 right？

Comment: @Crashalot That doesn't seem to make much difference. Maybe, 这家 is better than 那家 if you say it in this 咖啡店.

Comment: @Crashalot Another alternative could be: 自从上次以后，我这还是头一次来这家店。Better you put some context to make people think it's been long time since last time. E.g. 我上次来这家店是两年前。 自从上次以后，我这还是头一次来这家店。.

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong with the sentence, it sound very redundant.

If you had visited there before, any time you visit again would be the first time since the last time. The second part of the sentence doesn't add any useful information to the first part.

Let me change the sentence so it sound more natural

> "This is the first time we go to that coffee shop since 2003" (now we know it was a long time ago)

Translation:

> "這是我們自2003年以來第一次去那家咖啡店"
>
> "這是(this is) 我們 (we) 自2003年以來 (since 2003) 第一次 (the first time) 去(go to) 那家咖啡店 (that coffee shop)"

notice we put 'since 2003 (自2003年以來)' before 'the first time (第一次)', which is reversed in English as: 'the first time since 2003

- [**自** (XX)**以來**] = [**Since** (XX)]
- [**自** (上次我們去那間咖啡店) **以來**] = [**Since** (last time we went to that coffee shop)]

**Edit**:

> *could you kindly explain why you use 自 instead of 自從 or 從？i thought 從 was the abbreviation for 自從, not 自*

Both 自 and 從 can be used as abbreviation for 自從

- 自 = since/ from/ **begin at**
- 從 = since/ from/ **following**
- 自從 (begin at and following) = **since**

When you want to use 自 or 從 to express the meaning of "since"

you have to add 以來, 至 or 到 like below:

[自~ 以來]  e.g. 自古以來 (since ancient time)

[自~ 到]  e.g. 自古到今 (since/from ancient time to today)

[自~ 至] e.g. 自古至今 (since/from ancient time to today)

[從~ 以來] e.g. 從古以來 (since ancient time)

[從~ 到] e.g. 從古到今 (since/from ancient time to today)

[從~ 至] e.g. 從古至今 (since/from ancient time to today)

All are correct, (自 ~ 至) is more literary, (從 ~ 到) is more colloquial)

> *also would it be equally correct to say 以後 or 之後 instead of 以來*

"自2003年以來" emphasize the date we start counting (from 2003 to today)

"自2003年以後" emphasize 'what following that date' (after 2003)

You can use either

Comment: thanks again! could you kindly explain why you use 自 instead of 自從 or 從？i thought 從 was the abbreviation for 自從, not 自.

Comment: also would it be equally correct to say 以後 or 之後 instead of 以來？

Comment: @Crashalot see my editions.

Comment: thank you so much! the additions and all the examples are incredibly helpful.